# How to find whether the line is inside the polygon or outside.

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry

I have a polygon
[image]

How can i prove whether the black color line lies outside the polygon or inside the polygon .

Given the coordinates of the black line and all the vertices of the polygon.

Comment: If you know the coordinates of all vertices of the polygon, doesn't mean you know it's shape. Beacuse there are many ways to connect the vertices and as much as different shapes.

Comment: But in this case i know the shape and the coordinates are according to it.

Comment: is there any concept for proving this?

Comment: Do you want a general solution or a solution just for this problem?

Comment: this problem was for an example.Is there any general solution?

Comment: I assume that the OP knows the vertices *in a specific order*. So, he *does* know how they are connected, and the polygon is unambiguous.

Comment: Take one endpoint of the segment and use the crossing number process to see if it crosses any segments of the polygon. If it does you know the segment isn't wholly enclosed or outside; if it doesn't, use the same process with the crossing number algorithm to decide whether that initial endpoint is inside or outside the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

The picture in the question implies your only interested in the special case where each end of the line segment is on an edge of the polygon. In that case a set of necessary and sufficient conditions for the line segment to be interior (where "interior" includes the edges herein) are:

1. No edge of the polygon crosses the given line segment.
2. The line segment is "pointing inward".

There is a well known formulae for checking condition 1 on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection).

To explain the "pointing inward" condition, first it's easier to formulate in the special-special case where each end of the line is on a vertex. The above special (edge or vertex) case can be trivially converted: if an edge of the line segment is on an edge not a vertex, add a vertex there (still the same polygon ...).

For the "pointing inward" condition: notice for any polygon we can "walk" around the perimeter of any polygon always keeping the interior to one side (imagine walking around a building). Which side is inside depends direction we start walking but there is always one direction where a positive (anti-clockwise) rotation of a given edge vector is inwards. You can normalize the order of the vertices of you polygon by walking it, adding up the angles and checking they add up to $2\pi$, and if they don't reversing the order of the vertices.

In the following image, the green tab represents the direction of a positive rotation and the red arrow the direction of the edge vectors.

[image]

Now, given a line segment between vertices $(i,j)$, the angle between vectors $(i, i+1),  (i, j)$ needs to be within that between the vectors $(i-1, i), (i)$, and vice versa to $(j,i)$ rel the angle $(j-1,j), (j+1)$

Comment: Why down voted?

Answer (score -1):

If we have an $n$ points on a plane and we know their coordinates we can easily check whether given line cuts the polygon. So first here's explanation why this method works. Let say we have $n$ point on a plane, we can connect them in the way we like, but with one restriction that no two sides of the polygon cut each other. Then choose an arbitrary point and connect it with every other point. And at last draw a convex polygon, such that the original polygon is inscribed in it.

[image: diagram]

So in the picture: $ABCDEFG$ is the polygon we want to check if certain line cuts it, WLOG $B$ is our arbitrary point and $ABDEF$ is the convex polygon.

If a line cuts through $ABDEF$, the it also cuts $ABCDEFG$ and vice versa. Because if the line cuts the polygon the it will have one "penetration" and one "exit" point. Now we've reduced the polygon to a convex one.

We can now use the fact that if a line cuts a convex polygon then it also cuts at least one of the its diagonals or another line that cuts it inside the polygon.

As I said earlier using the slope formula we can obtain equation for any line ( because we don't know which point is a vertex of the convex polygon we find every possible segment no matter if its a side or a diagonal).

We know that two line intersect each other, unless they are parallel, but we are interested in a intersection in between the defining points of the segment.

To find if the intersection happens in the segment, do the following. For example use the segment $BC$ we already know the equation of the line that passes through it, so we find the intersection point with the line we want to know if it cuts the polygon. Let denote that point as $X$. Using distance formula find the length of the segments $BC, BX, CX$. If the following equation is satisfied then the lines intersect at segment $BC$:

$$|BX| + |CX| = |BC|$$

If it's true for one segment then you can stop and that means that the line cuts the polygon.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all... far from it.

_"If a line cuts through ABDEF, then it also cuts ABCDEFG and vice versa"_

That might be true for a line but not even remotely true for a segment. And by looking at the image in the question it is extremely obvious that the question is about a segment not a line. Sure, the OP didn't use the proper terms, but it's still fairly obvious.

Examples:
The segment `[[-3, 2], [-2, 2]]` cuts ABDEF **but not** ABCDEFG.
Similarly, the segment `[[-2, 1], [-1, 1]]` cuts ABCDEFG **but not** ABDEF.